# How can I create an array whose length is specified by a const argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have a function:

```
void f(const size_t &len){
    double arr[len];
}
```

but it doesn't work, because I got message from len, that "expression must have a constant value". How can I solve this problem, if I don't want to create a global variable len?

Comment: Could you provide [MRE]

Comment: `double* arr = new double[len];`? Or, even better, `std::vector<double> arr(len);`?

Comment: `const` and constant expression are different... Former is more "read-only" whereas later is "value known at compile time".

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Why do you want to do that ? Why not a `std::vector` ?

Comment: `std::vector<double> arr(len);`.

Comment: new() is slow for my big case, what about vector, Yes, maybe it was obviously, sorry

Comment: @KK_1999 Vectors just use `new` internally (allocate memory).

Comment: "new() is slow for my big case" - have you tested this?

Comment: By the way what difference between vector<T> and usual array in C++? Can usual array be faster than std::vector?

Comment: @KK_1999 Memory layout of elements is the very same (contiguous storage). From this perspective, there are no differences.

Comment: @KK_1999 Note that an interesting trade-off solution might be for you a vector with _small data/buffer optimization_, such as `boost::container::small_vector`. But it depends on the values of `len` in your code runs.

Comment: @DanielLangr and `sizeof(T)`. E.g. never really applicable to `std::vector<double>`

Comment: I tried to use vector but unfortunately it was slow solution for me

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not support variable-length arrays. If `len` is a compile time constant, I'd advise you to use `std::array` with a template, like so:

```
template<size_t len>
void f(){
    std::array<double, len> arr;
    //use arr
}
```

And you would use it like that:

```
int main()
{
    f<5>();
}
```

Do note, that the `5` in my example is a compile-time constant. If you do not know the size of your array at compile time, use a `std::vector`. You'd do this like this:

```
void f(const size_t len){
    std::vector<double> arr(len);
    //use arr
}

int main()
{
    size_t variableLength = 0;
    std::cin >> variableLength;
    f(variableLenght);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Dynamic Array (On the free store). using one of the memory allocation functions.

```
double* arr = new double[len];
```

But you have to keep track of the memory release yourself!! so you have to Save your pointer as a global variable or as a class member to delete it later using

```
delete[] arr;
arr = nullptr;
```

This is how Dynamic arrays are managed in c++, but static arrays are created on the stack of an instruction block and they are destroyed automatically.And theire size must be defined at compile time not at run time.

Comment: _But you have to keep track of the memory release yourself!_ — That's why it's so much preferred to use a `vector`.

Comment: @ Daniel Langr. Yes you are right but is very important and benefic to be familiar with memory managment. because this is the strong point in a Low level programing Language. Otherwise i would go for something else like Java or C# where all this stuff is hidden from the programmer

Comment: _Otherwise i would go for something else like Java or C#..._ — Agree, but one isn't always so lucky to have this choice ;-).